# Is it possible to keep original trailing zeroes from C# decimal type when saving in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, decimal, precision

I would like to find a simple way to keep trailing zeroes from C# decimal type when saving in SQL Server.
Example:

- 5.3 and save, the system should display 5.3 after reloading.
- 05.30 and save, the system should display 5.30
- 5.300 and save, the system should display 5.300 after reloading.

The C# decimal type seems to do it well but the SQL server decimal type not.
For example, I would define the SQL Server column as decimal(9,3) and all 3 values would be saved as 5.300.

Of course, I could convert to string but I just wonder if there is any more elegant solution if any computing is needed on this field.

Comment: Are those values not identical?

Comment: This sounds like a display problem for your applications UI to solve, rather than a data storage problem.  Those values are all the same.

Comment: What's the reason you need to do this? Knowing that might help others to find the best solution.

Comment: @John their value is, but their *precision* is not. You can assume 5.300 to be accurate to +/- 0.001.

Comment: When you store a numeric value you generally can not store "extras" like its precision. It would be a huge waste of space because people would rarely use it. And memory costs money.

Comment: @chris544 your comment is a bit perplexing. The precision of a numeric value is not an "extra". It is part of the datatype.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, data type has a precision that it supports (something more like its resolution), but generally you cannot store the real precision of a particular value.

Comment: All rows in a given have the same precision. If you are saying something about changing precision on a row basis then that is correct because that is not how relational data works.

Comment: I know these values are identical. These values are weights input by users. It has to be displayed as it has been input by the user so if there were 2 trailing zeroes, the display should keep these 2 trailing zeroes (after reloading from DB).

Comment: Then, I think the most simple solution is to store original user's input in the additional column. It is better than store number of trailing zeroes, because your task is "it has to be displayed as it has been input by the user". With such task, solution is - save user input

Answer (score 4):

I think it is not a good idea to mix DB and UI layers. How the SQL stores data is the DB problem, and how to show type to the user is a UI problem.

C# stores Decimal in the format, using the base 10:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits.aspx

Internal representation:

```
1m      : 0x00000001 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
1.0000m : 0x000186a0 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00050000
```

AFAIK, the internal representation of decimal in MSSQL is not documented. And, if the are using the following floating point format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985
then it is impossible.

But, there are parameters of the decimal in MSSQL like precision and scale. One can try to use ADO.NET to manipulate this parameters in the code like this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("command", new SqlConnection("connection"));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.Decimal,18);
cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Precision = 18;
cmd.Parameters["@p1"].Scale = 8;
```

Then, it can be possible, but, anyway it is a really hacking method, and you should not use this in the production

Comment: In C#: `(5.3m).ToString() == "5.3"` and `(5.300m).ToString() == "5.300"`

Comment: Try passing in a variable that was set to 5.3 or 5.30.

Comment: I know about the internal representation that is different but this is not helping to solve my issue, see my comment here below about these data being weights input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number of significant figures (or precision, if that's all you're interested in) for a numeric value to vary on a row-by-row basis you'll need to have a separate column that stores that number as a single numeric column isn't going to store that information.

If the number of significant figures (or precision) is consistent for all of the rows, then you can simply store the data in the database with as much precision as the database supports and then convert it back to what it should be within your application before presenting it to the user.

Comment: This is the solution I had a mind so far. I don't want to keep additional information about significant figures if not absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the column type of SQL Server as [`sql_variant`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181071.aspx).

When you set a value of *decimal*(C#) to that column via `SqlParameter`, SQL Server keeps the metadata including scale of the value.

Comment: Seems interesting. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed it seems to work. Though, it is very unlikely that the custom framework (data access code generated) we developed will support this column type. Besides, I doubt this is a good idea to use 'untyped' column in a DB.